# Image file extension randomly is missing in sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I'm experiencing an strange behaviour in our production servers.
We have three servers and It seems sometimes MediaManager.GetMediaUrl doesn't return the file extension. First I thought one server might have different settings. I compared all the configs on the three servers and they are identical.
Surprisingly, I notice If I browse the same page from the same server I can replicate issue.

I checked the value of Media.RequestExtension and for all three is same as following

```
<setting name="Media.RequestExtension" value=""/>
```

I cannot replicate the issue on none of our environments( local,test, staging )

I added the metatag and hardcoded the server name and I set the Cacheable property of usercontrol to false and I'm sure it's not Caching issue.

```
 var images = new List<string>();
                    var imageField1 = (Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField)Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["og Image1"];
                    if (imageField1 != null && imageField1.MediaItem != null)
                    {
                        var image1Url = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(imageField1.MediaItem);
                        images.Add(image1Url);

                    }
```

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Comment: Did you try clearing the sitecore media cache from all servers? Can you try to identify which one server is causing this problem? May be you can take that server off from load balancer briefly and check to see if issue gets resolved.

Comment: Can you add please also the language to your mediaurl? I met this problem,I don't know if is really the same but I added languages to mediaurl and it works: MediaUrlOptions mediaUrlOptions = new MediaUrlOptions                                                      {    Language = Sitecore.Context.Language  };
                return Sitecore.StringUtil.EnsurePrefix('/', MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(item, mediaUrlOptions));

Answer (score 0):

Even I have faced this issue of extension in media item urls.
Workaround for this issue would be to make use of **IncludeExtension** property of **MediaUrlOptions** object.

```
MediaUrlOptions mediaUrlOpts = new MediaUrlOptions();
mediaUrlOpts.IncludeExtension = false;
Response.Write(MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(item, mediaUrlOpts ));
```

If you want to always add extension to URL, then set **IncludeExtension** to true.